# update command to replace values in a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that contains a 10-digit number. I need to replace the last 2 digits in each row with different ending numbers. All records at this time have an ID# ending in '14' and I want to update them all to end in '24' The leading 8 digits of each ID will stay the same.

Example: ID# Value is '1097845514' I need it to be ID# '1097845524'.

Thanks for any/all help.

Comment: You probably want to mention which database you're using.

Comment: Oops...looking for a SQL Command. Working in MS SQL Server 2005 Management Studio

Comment: use UPDATE table SET id=id+10

Comment: @aaa put that as answer and the OP will have to accept it (hopefully)!

Comment: @Edper it's ok I'm happy my suggestion helped Jam. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seams like your id you need to increment with 10 all the time but if that is not the case you need to find the difference between the id to next value which is ending with 24 and add to id

let's say if the difference is of 'x' then

```
 UPDATE table SET Id = Id + x
```